# Fill a template with all possible combinations

Tags: java, java-8, rdf

I have some kind of SPARQL query templates I want to fill. Therefore I have a mapping of replacements. Now I want to create every possible combination out of the replacements. I came up with the following "algorithm" (A link to the actual code is below!):

```
for(replacement in replacements){
    //replacement == "<NNP1>" -> "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile>"
    for(template in templates){
        //template == SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <^NNP4^> <^NN3^> ?x . <^NN2^> <^NN1^> ?uri }
        for(argument in template){
            //an argument is here everything inside the SPARL triple
            // "<^NNP4^> <^NN3^> ?x" has 3 arguments: <^NNP4^>, <^NN3^> and ?x
            //Note: There is definitely something wrong with the following if conditions!
            if(argument==replacement AND position isnt replaced before){
                //replacement.key == <^NNP1^>
                //replacement.value == <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile>
                template.replaceOnce(replacement.key, replacement.value)
                //In the triple "<^NNP4^> <^NN3^> ?x" 
                //<^NNP4^> would be position 0, <^NN3^> position 1 and ?x position 2
                save_position()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which creates this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <^NN3^> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <^NN3^> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <^NNP4^> <^NN3^> ?x . <^NN2^> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <^NNP4^> <^NN3^> ?x . <^NN2^> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?uri }
```

But it should be this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?uri }
```

**I created a testcase for you to try it out yourself under**: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/arx

I know that the part with `if(argument==replacement AND position isnt replaced before)` isn't correct, because as you see in the expected result, some replacements can be done in the same position more than once. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?uri }
SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/cityType> ?x . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/start> ?uri }
```

Both contain the same replacement (`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nile>`) in the same position.

Can someone give me a hint what the correct solution could look like or maybe provide me a better approach?

*Note:* The generated SPARQL queries are just examples, they don't have to make sense!

Comment: Probably it is easier to generate query of this kind: `SELECT DISTINCT ?uri
{
?s1 ?p1 ?x .
?s2 ?p2 ?uri .
FILTER ((?s1 != ?s2) && (?p1 != !p2))
VALUES (?s1) {(dbo:Nile) (dbo:Country)}
VALUES (?s2) {(dbo:Nile) (dbo:Country)}
VALUES (?p1) {(dbo:start) (dbo:cityType)}
VALUES {?p2} {(dbo:start) (dbo:cityType)}
}`

Comment: This definatly looks better than my approach. I'll give it a try!